# Image mouse click effect like Windows 8 Start menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image, And I want to create an effect like Windows 8 start menu when user clicks on it.

I mean, if this is my image:

[image]

When user clicks on it, it should change to something like this:

[image]

I mean, a little 3D effect.

How to create this effect in code behind? (On `MouseDown` event)

Comment: I think your issue was covered by this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237824/c-wpf-image-transformation-over-a-trapezoid).

Comment: @Rafal Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you requested I'm posting my answer again:

Solution to your issue is covered by another SO question:

[C#/WPF image transformation over a trapezoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237824/c-wpf-image-transformation-over-a-trapezoid)

Hope this time it wont be automatically converted to comment :)