# Transform image in WPF application

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I have a WPF application and I need to transform an image. I would like to add a 3-D perspective efftect like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700359.aspx).

But this code only exists in Silverlight :

```
<Image.Projection>
    <PlaneProjection RotationX="-35"   />
</Image.Projection>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in WPF ? Or something thaht look like it...

Edit : I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34391/Rotating-WPF-Content-in-D-Space) but what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: See the [3-D Graphics Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no "simple" way to do it ? I'm a beginner and it seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Not like your Silverlight example, no.

Comment: I found a solution [here][1] using the WPF 3D


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237824/c-wpf-image-transformation-over-a-trapezoid